# How to iterate through a Python list and return the number of pairs in which values are the same

Tags: python-3.x

All my trials failed since I am a beginner.
as an example:

```py
a = [1,2,5,9,7,1,5]

# output should be 2 because we
# have 2 pairs with same elements
# each: 1,1 and 5,5
```

Comment: Can you show your code that failed...

Comment: hi chris, all my trials are a real laughing mess that iam ashamed to show them

Comment: As suggestion, you could make use of the Counter class from the collections module, that will count for you how many of each number is. You can then use floor division to check how many pairs of each number there is. Lastly you can use sum to sum the number of pairs giving you a total count

Comment: Can you have 3, or more times the same values? How would you count it then?

Comment: Never be ashamed to show. People will be much more willing to help someone whos made an attempt than someone who looks like they didnt even try the problem and just want an answer

Comment: Hi Grzegorz. Actually I have a list where an element could be times 2 only. thank you.

Comment: @ChrisDoyle ok iam gonna follow your instructions and go back again. may i send you later my trial?

Comment: Of course we are always happy to help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that there will only be two and not three of any one element, this should do the job.

```
print (len (a) - len (set (a)))
```

Comment: thank you bro. and you understand my feeling of "could not do anything" and i need to learn at least the method to use. what i was trying is to make 2 lists and then del the none repeating one but i failed im counting the final list in pairs because i never knew or exactly i still did not learned  that len set could do the job. they are giving us advanced homework not in the running learning level, thats why i always stucked in there. thank you again. respect.